# aurae/retrofit-logansquare, LoganSquareConverterFactory IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter

Tags: android, json, logan-square

I am using aurae/retrofit-logansquare to parse json in my android retrofit project. I have added .addConverterFactory(LoganSquareConverterFactory.create()) as per the documentation.

Model Class

```
 import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonField;
import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
@JsonObject()
public class DemoModel{
    @JsonField(name = "newsonair")
    private List<NewsOnAir> newsonair = new ArrayList<NewsOnAir>();

    public NewsOnAirList(List<NewsOnAir> newsonair) {
        this.newsonair = newsonair;
    }

    public List<NewsOnAir> getNewsonair() {
        return newsonair;
    }

    public void setNewsonair(List<NewsOnAir> newsonair) {
        this.newsonair = newsonair;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NewsOnAirList{" +
                "newsonair=" + newsonair +
                '}';
    }
}
```

While running fatal exception Unable to create converter for class is happening.
Below is the error log.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class info.website.android.app.api.models.DemoModel.
                                                                            Tried:
                                                                             * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
                                                                             * com.github.aurae.retrofit2.LoganSquareConverterFactory
                                                                              at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:346)
                                                                              at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:308)
                                                                              at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:704)
```

Comment: You didn't add `@JsonObject` annotation on your `DemoModel` class.

Comment: Yes, I did add that annotation. I think its because of something else

Comment: It's because you don't have a parameterless default constructor, then.